# ASP.NET MVC context

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to store some data that's available across the entire MVC stack. I parse some information from `Request.FilePath` in `Application_BeginRequest`, then I need to refer to this information in controllers and a number of partial views.

Currently, I use `HttpContext.Current.Items`. Is there a better alternative in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Session, TempDataProvider, or HttpContext